# C Code - cannot insert new line via putchar.

Tags: c

I have a source code in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN_W 1
#define OUT_W 0
#define SPACE 32
#define TAB 9

int main() { 
    int c, state, temp;
    state = OUT_W;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((c != SPACE || c != TAB) && (state == OUT_W)) {
            state = IN_W;
            temp = c;
            c = 13;
            putchar(c);
            c = 10;
            putchar(c);
            putchar(temp);          
        } else if (c != SPACE || c != TAB)
            putchar(c);     
        else 
            state = OUT_W;      
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to achieve is I will type in some characters/words and catch those inputs by getchar. When ever getchar receive any characters besides space or tab, it will print a new line and then print those characters until it found a space or tab (abandon them). For example, when I type

```
123  eat    4bananas     in themorning
```

the program will print

```
123
eat
4bananas
in
themorning
```

I tried to integrate it with CR or LF, but it still print "123  eat     4bananas     in themorning".

My questions are:
1. What did I miss?
2. In the last 'else', which one is more efficient for the running program:

```
    else 
        state = OUT_W;
```

or

```
    else if ((c == SPACE || c == TAB) && state == IN_W)
        state = OUT_W;
    else
        continue;        // or can I use single ';' since we do nothing in here?
```

That's all. Thank you for your help.

Note: I tried playing with '\n' and '\t' too.

Regards,
Mario

Comment: Don't use "magic numbers" like 10 and 13 for character constants. Just use `' '` for space, `'\t'` for tab, and `'\n'` for newline. If you need the return character, you could use `'\r'` -- but you don't; writing `'\n'` to stdout will automatically generate the correct end-of-line sequence for your system, whether it's `LF` or `CR LF`.

Comment: Unless you're on a UNIX box talking to a device that requires DOS EOL characteristics of course :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start:

```
(c != SPACE || c != TAB)
```

is always true. A character cannot be both space and tab at the same time, hence it must *always* be either a non-tab or non-space. I suspect you meant:

```
(c != SPACE && c != TAB)
```

That's why the state is *never* going back to `OUT_W`, because after the first line end sequence, the second `if` statement is always true, so it will never get to that final `else` bit.

The following code works okay:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN_W 1
#define OUT_W 0
#define SPACE 32
#define TAB 9

int main (void) {
    int c, state, temp;
    state = OUT_W;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((c != SPACE && c != TAB) && (state == OUT_W)) {
            state = IN_W;
            temp = c;
            c = 13;
            putchar(c);
            c = 10;
            putchar(c);
            putchar(temp);
        } else if (c != SPACE && c != TAB)
            putchar(c);
        else
            state = OUT_W;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

although it still has that annoying initial newline, which you can fix by simply setting the initial state to `IN_W`.

There's also a lot of magic numbers in your code and some rather unnecessary moving of values. Possibly a more polished version would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN_W 1
#define OUT_W 0

#define SPACE ' '
#define TAB '\t'
#define CR '\r'
#define LF '\n'

int main (void) {
    int c, state;

    state = IN_W;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((c != SPACE) && (c != TAB) && (state == OUT_W)) {
            putchar(CR);
            putchar(LF);
            putchar(c);
            state = IN_W;
        } else if ((c != SPACE) && (c != TAB))
            putchar(c);
        else
            state = OUT_W;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

One thing I will mention is that it's often preferable to separate the state machine itself from the actions carried out. To that end, I would make the primary choice based on the current state rather than the character/state pair, and separate the actions for each state from the state machine.

I think that makes things a lot more readable, and easier to modify:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum tState { ST_WORD, ST_SPACE };

static enum tState doWord (int ch) {
    if ((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t')) {
        putchar ('\r');
        putchar ('\n');
        return ST_SPACE;
    }
    putchar (ch);
    return ST_WORD;
}

static enum tState doSpace (int ch) {
    if ((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t'))
        return ST_SPACE;
    putchar (ch);
    return ST_WORD;
}

int main (void) {
    int ch;
    enum tState state = ST_WORD;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (state) {
            case ST_WORD:  state = doWord  (ch); break;
            case ST_SPACE: state = doSpace (ch); break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, it's really an enlightenment I got. I will play with your suggestion. I think I need more exercise to train my logic and to get better understanding in how to use programming to solve my problem. Thank-you.

Answer (score 3):

This expression is not what you want: `(c != SPACE || c != TAB)`

This is always true.  If `c` is `SPACE` then it is not `TAB`, so the second part would be true.  If `c` is TAB then it is not `SPACE` so the first part would be true.

In both cases, what you want is `(c != SPACE && c != TAB)`  This is only true when `c` is not `SPACE` and also not `TAB`.  The operator `&&` is Boolean "and".

Also, I suggest that instead of magic numbers like `13` you should use C character constants like `'\r'`.

As for your second question, your program is not too bad as written.  I definitely don't think you would improve it by putting in a `continue` and I don't even quite see how it would work.  (As you noted, if the `else continue;` is at the very end of the loop, you can leave out the `continue`; actually, you could then just chop off the whole `else`, because `else;` does nothing.)

You have written a little state machine.  You have three interesting cases:

- in state OUT_W, need to transition to state IN_W  (And here is where you print the CR/LF to go to the next line)
- in state IN_W, found another character, stay in IN_W (here you print the character)
- in state IN_W, found a tab or space so need to transition to state OUT_W

There is a fourth possibility:

- in state OUT_W, found another tab or space, stay in OUT_W (handled just fine by the third case)

If you want the most efficient code, I think it would be best to rearrange it so that you only need to check for `SPACE` and `TAB` in one place:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == SPACE || c == TAB) {
        state = OUT_W;
    }
    else {
        /* c is not SPACE or TAB so we will print it */
        if (state == OUT_W) {
            /* transition from OUT_W to IN_W */
            state = IN_W;
            putchar('\r');
            putchar('\n');
            putchar(c);
        }
        else 
            putchar(c);
    }
}
```

And with this restructured version of the code, it becomes clear that any time you are in IN_W you print the character, but only on the transition you print the CR/LF.  So you could shorten this to not have an `else`, always call `putchar(c);`, but do that after the check for the transition.  I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I'm glad I made mistakes. I never thought about '\r' character before and the OR expression usage really slip through my mind. Thank-you for your time.